# Rails - Return all users given parameter gives ArguemntError (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, parameter-passing

I have a User model with two columns and trying to create a method that accepts a username parameter and returns all Users with the given parameter:

```
def find_user_byname(username)
  @user = User.all(username)
end
```

However, this returns an argument error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Model.all should return all, correct? Why is the error being given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is on the `all` method. It does not take arguments. You could do something like this instead:

```
@user = User.find_by(username: username)
```

assuming the property represented by the argument `username` is also called `username`.

Alternatively, if you want ALL users with that username (if there can be more than one), you could use:

```
@user = User.where(username: username)
```

`find_by` returns only one (the first) matching record, `where` returns all matching records.

ALSO, I should point out, if your model has a property called `username`, Rails will automatically provide you with the following method:

```
User.find_by_username
```

Which, like `find_by`, returns only the first record with the matching username.

Comment: Ah, hallelujah. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure. I notice you haven't accepted the answer, though. Is there more to this issue that needs to be answered?